# Black Screen with Cursor After Nvidia Update in Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, nvidia

Trying to "fix" an error, I seem to have made things worse. Upon boot, I was getting a failure of some sort. I got details by trying to send a bug report and it said it was something about building nvidia 410 that failed. Not sure why it was building it upon boot and everything was still working despite the error. To fix it, however, I thought I'd simply update my nvidia graphics. I found 430 was the most recent and so I installed that after purging the original stuff. I rebooted to get only a black screen that seems to go nowhere. The best it would show was a single [  OK  ] with something about LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.

I can get into GRUB by spamming shift and thus use the root terminal, but nothing I do seems to fix anything. I uninstalled nvidia entirely, hoping for some default VGA graphics, but no dice. I tried simply reinstalling nvidia followed by "startx" and it says the following:

```
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Not sure what server it's referring to or if this part even matters, but I do have network access and can ping Google. Any suggestions? Need to get this back up and running!

EDIT:
I've gotten it as far as showing these errors now... And if I boot from an older kernel I can at least get to the login screen but then, after logging in, it goes right back to the login screen. Meh.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, for some reason I simply needed to roll back to an older nvidia driver. I guess 430 is simply not compatible. No clue why default drivers didn't work when I uninstalled, but I installed 418 and all was well.